# session replication without loadbalancer

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to set up **session replication** between two tomcat servers(`server1`,`server2`) in two different machines.
I am using `StaticMembershipInterceptor` and `StaticMember` instead of `Multicast`. I am not using any loadbalancer.
Below is the site mainly I have followed. I referred this configuration as this is the exact requirement I have.

http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/tomcat-cluster-session-replication-without-multicasting

I am using **Tomcat9**.

What I am expecting is after the above configuration is:

Server1: Tomcat A
Server2: Tomcat B

**Exected Result :**

*Firststep*:
I start the Tomcat A. Load the webpage.(**http://server1:8080**) Login to application by entering username and password and  session is created.

*Secondstep*:
I start the Tomcat B. Load the webpage.(**http://server2:8080**). It should automcatically login to the application without entering username and password. No login page should be available.

**Actual Result after the above configuration:**

In Secondstep: Login page is available. the reason why login page appears is it creates different session.

When I tested the same configuration in the two nodes of same machine, it works fine. But in different machine, it does not work.

**What I tried so far:**

- Checked the log file of two tomcats - I can see the connection is
  established.
- Made sure   has distributable tag
- Also added the same in context.xml
- Tried adding inside the  tag as I saw it in couple of forum.
- Checked netstat -ano I could see ports are listening at 4100 in both
  the machines

Am I missing any other configuration? Not sure why it does not work.

Comment: Login is tied to a cookie.  So you'll have a cookie for server1 but server2 can't see that cookie.  That's why you have a load balancer so that there is a single hostname for both servers.

Comment: @stdunbar Thank you very much for you comments. It is clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using cookie-based session-tracking, because it is enabled by default and is preferred over URL-based session-tracking in Tomcat if the client is willing to send JSESSIONID cookies.

Cookies are scoped to a particular hostname and path. So, when you login to Tomcat A (http://server1:8080), you get a cookie scoped to `server1/path`. Wen you visit Tomcat B (http://server2:8080), your cookie for `server1` isn't sent and you are challenged to login.

If you want this to work, you will need to choose one of the following options:

1. Use a reverse-proxy / load-balancer
2. Use multiple-IP DNS to resolve `server` (not `server` or `server2`) to multiple IP addresses, each pointing to a separate Tomcat instance
3. Disable cookie-based session tracking

But the way you are testing things cannot work due to the rules browsers follow for HTTP cookie handling.

Comment: @Schults, It makes sense. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.